# Removal of statistically significant intercept term increases $R^2$ in linear model

Tags: r, linear-model, interpretation, r-squared, intercept

In a simple linear model with a single explanatory variable,

$\alpha_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \delta_i + \epsilon_i$

I find that removing the intercept term improves the fit greatly (value of $R^2$ goes from 0.3 to 0.9). However, the intercept term appears to be statistically significant.

With intercept:

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = alpha ~ delta, data = cf)
>
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -0.72138 -0.15619 -0.03744  0.14189  0.70305 
>
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)  0.48408    0.05397    8.97   <2e-16 ***
> delta        0.46112    0.04595   10.04   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
>
> Residual standard error: 0.2435 on 218 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared: 0.316,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.3129 
> F-statistic: 100.7 on 1 and 218 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

Without intercept:

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = alpha ~ 0 + delta, data = cf)
>
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -0.92474 -0.15021  0.05114  0.21078  0.85480 
>
> Coefficients:
>       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> delta  0.85374    0.01632   52.33   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
>
> Residual standard error: 0.2842 on 219 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared: 0.9259,   Adjusted R-squared: 0.9256 
> F-statistic:  2738 on 1 and 219 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

How would you interpret these results? Should an intercept term be included in the model or not?

**Edit**

Here's the residual sums of squares:

```
RSS(with intercept) = 12.92305
RSS(without intercept) = 17.69277
```

Comment: I recall $R^2$ to be the ratio of explained to total variance ONLY if the intercept is included. Otherwise it can't be derived and loses its interpretation.

Comment: @Momo: Good point. I've calculated the residual sums of squares for each model, which seem to suggest that the model with intercept term is a better fit regardless of what $R^2$ says.

Comment: Well, the RSS has to go down (or at least not increase) when you include an additional parameter. More importantly, much of the standard inference in linear models does not apply when you suppress the intercept (even if it's not statistically significant).

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7357

Comment: What $R$ does when there is no intercept is that it calculates $$R^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{\sum_i y_i^2}$$ instead (notice, no subtraction of the mean in the denominator terms). This makes the denominator larger which, for the same or similar MSE causes the $R^2$ to increase.

Comment: @cardinal: Makes sense. So, to summarize, without intercept the $R^2$ is larger but it's not comparable to the $R^2$ of the model with intercept. Instead, the sum of squared residuals can be used to compare the goodness of fit of both models. Correct?

Comment: The $R^2$ is not *necessarily* larger. It's only larger without an intercept as long as the MSE of the fit in both cases are similar. But, note that as @Macro pointed out, the numerator *also* gets larger in the case with no intercept so it depends on which one wins out! You're correct that they shouldn't be compared to one another but you *also* know that the SSE with intercept will *always* be smaller than the SSE without intercept. This is part of the problem with using in-sample measures for regression diagnostics. What is your end goal for the use of this model?

Comment: @cardinal: the end goal is to express $\alpha$ as a function of $\delta$. To put some perspective, $\alpha_i$ and $\delta_i$ are maximum likelihood estimators from another model (call it model A). What I want is reduce the number of parameters of model A. So if I can say $\alpha = k \delta$, for example, then I can change the specification of model A and cut the number of parameters in half (minus one), which is what I want.

Comment: see this link for an explanation: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171240/how-can-r2-have-two-different-values-for-the-same-regression-without-an-inte/171250#171250

Answer (score 187, accepted):

First of all, we should understand what the `R` software is doing when no intercept
is included in the model. Recall that the usual computation of $R^2$
when an intercept is present is
$$
R^2 = \frac{\sum_i (\hat y_i - \bar y)^2}{\sum_i (y_i - \bar
y)^2} = 1 - \frac{\sum_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{\sum_i (y_i - \bar
y)^2} \>.
$$
The first equality *only* occurs because of the inclusion of the
intercept in the model *even though* this is probably the more popular
of the two ways of writing it. The *second* equality actually provides
the more general interpretation! This point is also address in [this
related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7357).

**But, what happens if there is no intercept in the model?**

Well, in that
case, `R` (**silently!**) uses the modified form
$$
R_0^2 = \frac{\sum_i \hat y_i^2}{\sum_i y_i^2} = 1 - \frac{\sum_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{\sum_i y_i^2} \>.
$$

It helps to recall what $R^2$ is trying to measure. In the former
case, it is comparing your current model to the *reference*
model that only includes an intercept (i.e., constant term). In the
second case, there is no intercept, so it makes little sense to
compare it to such a model. So, instead, $R_0^2$ is computed, which
implicitly uses a reference model corresponding to **noise only**.

In what follows below, I focus on the second expression for both $R^2$ and $R_0^2$ since that expression generalizes to other contexts and it's generally more natural to think about things in terms of residuals.

**But, how are they different, and when?**

Let's take a brief digression into some linear algebra and see if we
can figure out what is going on. First of all, let's call the fitted
values from the model *with* intercept $\newcommand{\yhat}{\hat
{\mathbf y}}\newcommand{\ytilde}{\tilde {\mathbf y}}\yhat$ and the
fitted values from the model *without* intercept $\ytilde$.

We can rewrite
the expressions for $R^2$ and $R_0^2$ as 
$$\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf y}\newcommand{\one}{\mathbf 1} 
R^2 = 1 - \frac{\|\y - \yhat\|_2^2}{\|\y - \bar y \one\|_2^2} \>, 
$$
and
$$
R_0^2 = 1 - \frac{\|\y - \ytilde\|_2^2}{\|\y\|_2^2} \>,
$$
respectively.

Now, since $\|\y\|_2^2 = \|\y - \bar y \one\|_2^2 + n \bar y^2$, then $R_0^2 > R^2$ if and only if
$$
\frac{\|\y - \ytilde\|_2^2}{\|\y - \yhat\|_2^2} < 1 + \frac{\bar
y^2}{\frac{1}{n}\|\y - \bar y \one\|_2^2} \> .
$$

The left-hand side is greater than one since the model corresponding
to $\ytilde$ is nested within that of $\yhat$. The second term on the
right-hand side is the squared-mean of the responses divided by the
mean square error of an intercept-only model. So, the larger the mean of the response relative to the other variation, the more "slack" we have and a greater chance of $R_0^2$ dominating $R^2$.

Notice that all the
model-dependent stuff is on the left side and non-model dependent
stuff is on the right.

**Ok, so how do we make the ratio on the left-hand side small?**

Recall that
$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbf P}\ytilde = \P_0 \y$ and $\yhat = \P_1 \y$ where $\P_0$ and $\P_1$ are
projection matrices corresponding to subspaces $S_0$ and $S_1$ such
that $S_0 \subset S_1$.

So, in order for the ratio to be close to one, we need the subspaces
$S_0$ and $S_1$ to be very similar. Now $S_0$ and $S_1$ differ only by
whether $\one$ is a basis vector or not, so that means that $S_0$
had better be a subspace that already lies very close to $\one$.

In essence, that means our predictor had better have a strong mean
offset itself and that this mean offset should dominate the variation
of the predictor.

**An example**

Here we try to generate an example with an intercept explicitly in the model and which behaves close to the case in the question. Below is some simple `R` code to demonstrate.

```
set.seed(.Random.seed[1])

n <- 220
a <- 0.5
b <- 0.5
se <- 0.25

# Make sure x has a strong mean offset
x <- rnorm(n)/3 + a
y <- a + b*x + se*rnorm(x)

int.lm   <- lm(y~x)
noint.lm <- lm(y~x+0)  # Intercept be gone!

# For comparison to summary(.) output
rsq.int <- cor(y,x)^2
rsq.noint <- 1-mean((y-noint.lm$fit)^2) / mean(y^2)
```

This gives the following output. We begin with the model *with* intercept.

```
# Include an intercept!
> summary(int.lm)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max
-0.656010 -0.161556 -0.005112  0.178008  0.621790

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.48521    0.02990   16.23   <2e-16 ***
x            0.54239    0.04929   11.00   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.2467 on 218 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.3571,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.3541
F-statistic: 121.1 on 1 and 218 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Then, see what happens when we *exclude* the intercept.

```
# No intercept!
> summary(noint.lm)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + 0)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-0.62108 -0.08006  0.16295  0.38258  1.02485

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
x  1.20712    0.04066   29.69   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.3658 on 219 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.801,      Adjusted R-squared: 0.8001
F-statistic: 881.5 on 1 and 219 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Below is a plot of the data with the model-with-intercept in red and the model-without-intercept in blue.

[image: Data plot with regression lines]

Comment: This is really spectacular, +1. A question: often when we want to adjudicate b/t 2 models, we perform a nested model test, does this preclude that, or would it still be valid to test a reduced model w/o the intercept against a full model w/ it?

Comment: @gung: No, I don't believe there is anything precluding us from the typical $F$-test. The test does not depend on the presence of an intercept, and, indeed, I believe the $F$-statistic will work out in this case to be $$F = (n-2) \left(\frac{\|\y - \ytilde\|_2^2}{\|\y - \yhat\|_2^2} - 1 \right)$$. This gives us a bit of quantitative information in that, if indeed $R_0^2 > R_1^2$, then we know that $$F < (n-2) \frac{\bar y^2}{n^{-1} \|\y - \bar y \one\|_2^2} \>,$$ assuming, of course, I've done the algebra correctly.

Comment: I prefer the expression $R_0^2=\frac{\Vert \tilde Y \Vert^2}{\Vert Y \Vert^2}$

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: (+1) Thanks for the comment; maybe I should include it in the answer for completeness. The reasons I did not use this form are two-fold: (a) The form I've given more readily generalizes, particularly to non-projection operators, as alluded to in the answer and (b) I believe most people think more naturally about the size of residuals than the size of the approximations. You can arrive at the same result, of course, but not quite so directly. Cheers.

Comment: Where you say "the intercept isn't included in the model", isn't it more true that it,*is* included, but not as a free variable? (Its fixed at 0)

Comment: @naught101: I would not say it is *more* true, but it is an equally reasonable viewpoint, generally speaking. For the present exposition, it is convenient to consider it as absent in the sense that we are ultimately interested in the relationship between the subspaces $S_1$ and $S_0$. The difference between the two is the presence, or lack thereof, of the basis vector $\mathbf 1$.

Comment: I'm missing something. Is what R does, _correct_? I mean is the R^2 value that is reported, even remotely comparable between the with and without intercept cases?

Comment: @cardinal what is this "predictor mean offset" ("predictor had better have a strong mean offset")?

Comment: @cardinal Not to beat a dead horse, but I was also curious about Andy Clifton's question above. Is there a good reference on R^2 definition when the model has been fitted without an intercept?

Comment: see also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171240/how-can-r2-have-two-different-values-for-the-same-regression-without-an-inte/171250#171250

Comment: I am unable to tell from either the current answer or the comment thread to go with it whether the poster is advocating for dropping the y-intercept as a means of boosting R^2 or not.  What is your conclusion based on all of this analysis?

Comment: @cardinal Can you explain what do you mean by "reference model corresponding to noise only"? Do we assume that the model always predicts $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N} (0, 1)$?

Answer (score 2):

I would base my decision on an information criteria such as the Akaike or Bayes-Schwarz criteria rather than R^2; even then I would not view these as absolute.

If you have a process where the slope is near zero and all of the data is far from the origin, your correct R^2 should be low as most of the variation in the data will be due to noise. If you try to fit such data to a model without an intercept you will generate a large and wrong slope term and likely a better looking R^2 if the intercept free version is used.

The following graph shows what happens in this extreme cases.
Here the generating process is that x=100,100.1,.... and y is just 100 + random noise with mean 0 and standard deviation .1. The points are black circles, the fit without the intercept is the blue line and the fit with the intercept (zeroing out the slope) is the red line:

[Sorry it won't let me post the graph; run the R-code below to generate it. It shows the origin in the lower left corner, the cluster of points in the upper right corner. The bad no-intercept fit goes from the lower left to the upper right and the correct fit is a line parallel to the x-axis]

The correct model for this should have an R^2 of zero---be a constant plus random noise.  R will give you and R^2 of .99 for the fit with no intercept. This won't matter much if you only use the model for prediction with x-values within the  range of the training data, but will fail miserably if x goes outside of the narrow range of the training set or you are trying to gain true insights beyond just prediction.

The AIC correctly shows that the model with the intercept is preferred.
The R code for this is:

```
 Nsamp=100
x=seq(1,100,1)*.1+100 # x=101.1,101.2,....
y=rnorm(n=length(x))+100 # random noise +100 (best model is constant)

model_withint=lm(y~x)
print(summary(model_withint))
flush.console()
model_noint=lm(y~x+0) 
print(summary(model_noint))
print (AIC(model_withint))
print(sprintf ('without intercept  AIC=%f',AIC(model_noint)))
print(sprintf ('with intercept  AIC=%f',AIC(model_withint)))
print(sprintf ('constant model  AIC=%f',AIC(lm(y~1))))
plot(x,y,ylim=c(0,105),xlim=c(0,105))
lines( c(0,105),c(0,105)*model_noint$coefficients['x'],col=c('blue'))
lines( c(0,105),c(1,1)*(lm(y~1)$coefficients['(Intercept)']),col=c('red'))
```

The AIC output is

```
   "without intercept  AIC=513.549626"
    "with intercept  AIC=288.112573"
    "constant model  AIC=289.411682"
```

Note that the AIC still gets the wrong model in this case, as the true model is the constant model; but other random numbers will yield data for which the AIC is lowest for the constant model. Note that if you discard the slope, you should refit the model without it, not try to use the intercept from the model and ignore the slope.

Answer (score 2):

The way in which the R software computes the R squared for the case of no intercept (see the answer by cardinal) produces inconsistent results.

Suppose that you have a single categorical explanatory variable that has only two categories (cat and dog).

Then you can write two completely equivalent regression models:

1. a regression on a constant and a dummy variable that encodes the cat category (1 if cat, 0 otherwise);
2. a regression without a constant and two dummy variables, one for cat and one for dog.

Since these models are completely equivalent, they should have the same R squared, but the R software will tell you that they have two different R squareds.

Bottom line: in general, the R squared calculated by R for the case of no intercept is hardly useful to compare two models. A more useful (and common) definition of R squared (which always makes sense, and coincides with that computed by R for regressions including a constant) is $$R^2 = 1 - \frac{MSE_{model}}{MSE_{mean}}$$ where $MSE_{model}$ is the mean squared prediction error of your model, and $MSE_{mean}$ is the mean squared prediction error obtained by predicting the dependent variable with its sample mean.

Comment: This is an interesting and valid comment.  It doesn't appear to answer the question, though.

Comment: I expanded the answer by adding a bottom line.