Forcing GLM with binomial distribution through zero intercept
I have been re-directed to cross-validated after my post here on stack-overflow. I want to force the intercept of a glm model with a binomial link function to be zero, since there are biological constraints on this relationship.  I have used the formula y ~ 0 + x to try and achieve this, however, when I do this, the y intercept is exactly 0.5.
# simulate relationship
set.seed(123)
# generate random x values between 0 and 60
x <- runif(400, 0, 60)
y <- 1 - exp(-0.075 * x) * rnorm(400, 0.7, 0.1)

data = data.frame(sr= x, fipar = y)
# Fit the GLM model with a custom link function
model <- glm(fipar ~ 0 + sr, 
             data = data, 
             family = binomial(link='logit'))

# Create an observed and predicted dataframe
data$predicted <- predict(model, data, type = "response",se.fit = T)$fit
data$se <- predict(model, data, type = "response",se.fit = T)$se.fit

# Plot the data and the model's predicted probabilities
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = sr, y = fipar)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21,fill='orange') +
  ylim(0,1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted), color = "green")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = predicted - se, ymax = predicted + se), alpha = 0.2)




As one comment on stack-overflow notes,

The logistic curve fit by a binomial distribution asymptotically approaches 0 on the left and 1 on the right, but it never actually reaches those values. You could force the curve arbitrarily far to the right to get the value at 0 to be as close to 0 as possible, but since it's symmetric around the inflection point that will mess up your fit.

Are there alternative models that might achieve what I need? Perhaps other r-packages that allow for different distributions?
Update
I tried fitting other models to achieve what I want, for example:
exp_model = nls(fipar ~ 1 - exp(-k * sr), 
                data = data, start = list(k = 0.0007))
data$exp_pred <- predict(exp_model, data)

This allows me to force the intercept at 0, however, the errors fall outside the bounds of 0 and 1, which is why I was using a glm with a binomial link function to begin with..


You could use binomial(link='identity') to force the intercept through zero. However, why are you trying to use a binomial model? A binomial model is generally used for binary outcomes (1/0, yes/no, success/failure). You look like you have some kind of continuous data bounded by 0 and 1.

Yes I have continuous data bound by 0 and 1. Are there more appropriate ways to deal with this type of data?

@AlexJ when I used the binomial(link='identity') the function becomes linear and ignores the shape of the relationship between x and y

You could try a Beta regression. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_regression . This is implemented in the betareg package in R.

I have an answer to your question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/274553/77222

Thanks! So a log transform on the y variable did the job.
