# In R there is a problem of intercept and without intercept ,Pearson's Correlation does not follow! Why? (see the bolded resuls)

Tags: r, correlation, lm, intercept

```
Xvec <- rnorm(200)
Yvec <- 2.6*Xvec + rnorm(200)

lmodxy <- lm(Xvec ~ Yvec)
lmodyx <- lm(Yvec ~ Xvec)
summary(lmodxy)
```

Output

```
Call:

lm(formula = Xvec ~ Yvec)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 

-0.85820 -0.24244  0.01888  0.23892  0.75319 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.015986   0.023954   0.667    0.505    
Yvec        0.336546   0.009412  35.758   <2e-16 ***
---

    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3379 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8659,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8652 
F-statistic:  1279 on 1 and 198 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Code

```
lmodxy$coefficients[2]*lmodyx$coefficients[2]
# Yvec: 0.865911394725732

cor(Yvec,Xvec)^2
# 0.865911394725732

lmodxy2 <- lm(Xvec ~ Yvec-1)
lmodyx2 <- lm(Yvec ~ Xvec-1)
summary(lmodxy2)
```

Output

```
 Call:
lm(formula = Xvec ~ Yvec - 1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.84247 -0.22664  0.03424  0.25282  0.76821 

Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Yvec 0.336094   0.009374   35.85   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3374 on 199 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8659,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8653 
F-statistic:  1285 on 1 and 199 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Code

```
lmodxy2$coefficients[1]*lmodyx2$coefficients[1]
#  Yvec: 0.865940634163253
```

Why the correlation squared is not the same as the product of slopes without intercepts whereas it is the same in the case of products with intercepts

it should be --------
`Y_hat = bX + a`   and `X_hat = BY + A` then `Cor(Y,X)^2 = (b*)(B*)`

Comment: And why do you think this equality must hold?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent cause when you remove intercepts you only pass that line through origin there is no change in Slopes ......so,   b  remains b and B remains B

Comment: See CrossValidated [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80790/deliberately-fitting-a-model-without-intercept).

Comment: No. When you fit the model without intercept, that means you derive the best fit of the form $y = bx$. That does not mean you remove the estimated intercept of the best fit of the form $y = a+bx$.