# Using the normal equations to calculate coefficients in multiple linear regression

Tags: r, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I am trying to understand how to get the coefficient of a multiple linear regression.

The formula is:

$b = (X'X)^{-1}(X')Y$

I try to calculate $b$ without package and with the `lm` package inside R.

Doing so, I got different results.

I want to know why. Did I made a mistake? Or does the `lm` package calculate differently because of the intercept?

```
> y <-  c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x2 <- c(1,4,5,7,9)
> Y <- as.matrix(y)
> X <- as.matrix(cbind(x1,x2))
> beta = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% Y) ; beta
            [,1]
x1  1.000000e+00
x2 -1.421085e-14
> model <- lm(y~x1+x2) ; model$coefficients
 (Intercept)           x1           x2 
1.191616e-15 1.000000e+00 1.192934e-15
```

[image: 3d]

## Update

As Alex and the other told me, it was a question of roundoff error. Therefore, I decided to take another data from the book "Essential Statistics for business and economics" by Anderson and all. In this case, the coefficients are the same in both `lm` function and in my own matrix.

```
> y <- c(9.3, 4.8, 8.9, 6.5, 4.2, 6.2, 7.4, 6, 7.6, 6.1)
> x0 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
> x1 <-  c(100,50,100,100,50,80,75,65,90,90)
> x2 <- c(4,3,4,2,2,2,3,4,3,2)
> Y <- as.matrix(y)
> X <- as.matrix(cbind(x0,x1,x2))

> beta = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% Y);beta
         [,1]
x0 -0.8687015
x1  0.0611346
x2  0.9234254
> model <- lm(y~+x1+x2) ; model$coefficients
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
 -0.8687015   0.0611346   0.9234254
```

Comment: You forgot to include a vector of 1 representing the intercept. The rest looks correct.

Comment: I changed only the  'X' as you suggested, but then I got different coefficients again.

Comment: For general information about the effects of suppressing (ie, not fitting) the intercept in a regression model, it may be useful to read this excellent CV thread: [Removal of statistically significant intercept term boosts $R^2$ in linear model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@MichaelMayer has it right. Try the following:

```
> y <-  c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x0 <- c(1,1,1,1,1)   # vector of ones representing the intercept
> x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x2 <- c(1,4,5,7,9)
> Y <- as.matrix(y)
> X <- as.matrix(cbind(x0,x1,x2))
> beta = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% Y) ;
```

**Update:** Even with the above changes you will still get slightly different results when you use `lm` due to roundoff error. If the estimated intercept and coefficient for x2 are nonzero, this is no longer visible.

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c(1,4,5,7,9)
y <-  x1 + x2 + rnorm(5,mean=0,sd=0.3);
Y <- as.matrix(y);
X <- as.matrix(cbind(1,x1,x2));
beta = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% Y) ; beta
model <- lm(y~1+x1+x2) ; model$coefficients
```

Output is:

```
         [,1]
   -0.2948504
x1  0.8081534
x2  1.1741777
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
 -0.2948504   0.8081534   1.1741777
```

For more info, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: When I do it I get different coefficient between 'lm' function and the manual way. lm gives 1.191616e-15 1.000000e+00 1.192934e-15  and the manual way gives 4.263256e-14 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00. Where the first number is the intercept then x1 and x2.

Comment: Those two answers are the same up to floating point roundoff error.  You should be comparing the coefficients *relative to their standard errors.*