# What is predictor offset in linear regression?

Tags: regression, predictor, definition, offset

I've been reading the post about removing intercept that boosts $R^2$ ([HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-boosts-r2-in-linear-model)). An answer to that post said that:

> In essence, that means our predictor had better have a strong mean
>   offset itself and that this mean offset should dominate the variation
>   of the predictor.

My question is: what is "a predictor mean offset"?
I've searched the Internet and found nothing :(

Comment: The quotation is a summary of the detailed explanation that precedes it.  You could take the preceding paragraph as @Cardinal's *definition* of "strong mean offset."

Comment: I like definitions by "X is sth, that...". Taking the paragraph does not change anything - I still don't understand, that's why I decided to ask a direct question.