# Which regression model to choose?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, r-squared

I have two models, one `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + 0)` which gives me a close to 0.90 something $R^2$ and another model `lm(y ~ x1 + x2)` which gives me a close to 0.0003 ish $R^2$. Based on $R^2$ one might choose the first model. I have domain (prior) knowledge that a 0 value of $x_1$ and a 0 value of $x_2$ should produce a 0 value of $y$. So, is my explicit setting of 0 a fair thing? Based on this knowledge and the obtained value of $R^2$ can I go with the first model?

***Edit***: From the threads [Removal of statistically significant intercept term increases $R^2$ in linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-boosts-r2-in-linear-model) and [When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-lm) I have learned that it is okay to do it as long as the domain knowledge above holds true. From [Is $R^2$ useful or dangerous?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous) I learned that $R^2$ alone is insufficient to make a decision about how good the model is. I need to look at AIC and BIC to make further decisions. However, because I my background is not in statistics, I am having trouble understanding the following in the first link:

1. Why does the first equality occur only when intercept is included?
2. why does $\bar{y}$ become 0 when intercept disappears?
3. Why in the second case, $R_0^2$ uses a reference model corresponding to **noise** only?
4. What is the $\bar{y_1}$ in the notation?
5. Why is $\|\ y \|_2^2 = \| y - \bar{y_1}\|_2^2 + n \bar y^2$ true?

Comment: Suppressing the intercept is almost never recommended (see: [When is it OK to remove the intercept in lm()](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7948/)). In addition, the $R^2$ values are not comparable (see: [Removal of statistically significant intercept term boosts $R^2$ in linear model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26176/)).

Comment: I think you will learn what you need in these threads. Please read through them. If you still have a question afterwards, come back here & edit your Q to state what you have learned & what you still need to understand, & we can re-open this & provide the information you need, rather than just duplicating material found elsewhere that wasn't enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) `+0` is the same as `-1` and it means that you want a model with no intercept. Also, if regression model is:

$$y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$$

so if $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, then:

$$y = \alpha + \beta_1 \times 0 + \beta_2 \times 0 = \alpha$$

so if you know that if $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ then $y=0$, it also means that *in this case* $\alpha$ has to be $0$.

On another hand, removing an intercept in many cases is not a good idea (as also gung suggeses in a comment). In your case model with no intercept will provide a perfect fit for values only in the case where $x_1 = x_2 = y = 0$, but could give worse fitting in other cases so you should consider if this idea is resonable.

However, you do **not** "explicitly set 0" in here, but remove an intercept (i.e. $\alpha$) from the model. $R^2$ also suggests that the model without intercept is better, however beware that $R^2$ values could be [misleading](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous) and you should not judge a model only basing on $R^2$.

Comment: I'm confused. what do you mean by "do **not** "explicitly set 0" in here, but remove an intercept " So, the way you suppress an intercept in R is by adding a +0 (or a -1) to the model right?

Comment: Yes, you remove intercept this way. If you meant that removing intercept is setting it to 0 than it seems I just have misunderstood you.