# $R^2$ in a model with no intercept is $R^2_u$, the uncentered $R^2$?

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, stata, goodness-of-fit

From [Hayashi, 2000, p.20](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s6946.pdf), I've understood that we can have some troubles in computing $R^2$ when the constant is not included in our model (e.g. negative $R^2$), but we can avoid them using $R^2_u = \hat{y}'\hat{y}/{y'y}$, the so-called uncentered $R^2$.

I've read also other discussion on the topic (e.g. [removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo)), but I have still some doubts:

Does the $R^2$ in a model without a constant become $R^2_u$ or the formulas stay different and we can look at $R^2_u$ as a solution in the case of constant absence?

How statistical softwares (`r`, `stata`) deal with this problem? I mean do they show automatically $R^2_u$ when the constant is not included or they show a wrong $R^2$?

Comment: "Does the $R^2$ in a model without a constant become $R^2_u$?" Certainly not, as $R^2_u$ is always nonnegative but $R^2$ may not be in a model without constant.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I was pretty sure about that but I've some problem in distinguishing between the two formulas. Does the $R^2$ still be $1-\frac{e'e}{y'M_{[1]}y}$? Even without the constant in the model I mean

Comment: As $R_u^2$ is far from universal notation, you need to define it.

Comment: @NickCox Sorry, I thought I wrote it

Comment: Thanks; I suggest that writing it as a fraction makes the font painfully small, especially for people with small monitors, so I've tweaked it.

Comment: OK, I tried an answer for that point, but the last two about R and Stata may be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the formula stays the same even if there is no constant. If there is a constant, the lower bound for $R^2$ of zero can be obtained from 
\begin{eqnarray}
y'M_{1}y&=&[M_{1}(Xb+e)]'[M_{1}(Xb+e)]\\
&=&b'X'M_{1}'M_{1}Xb+2e'M_{1}Xb+e'M_{1}'M_{1}e\\
&=&b'X'M_{1}Xb+2e'M_{1}Xb+e'M_{1}e\\
&=&b'X'M_{1}Xb+2e'Xb+e'e\\
&=&b'X'M_{1}Xb+e'e\\
&\geqslant&e'e
\end{eqnarray}
Here, the first three lines just multiply out and exploit symmetry and idempotency of $M_1$.

In the fourth line, we exploit that regressors and residuals are orthogonal in the sense that $X'e=0$. If $1\in\langle X\rangle$ (the case if there is a constant), we thus also have $1'e=0$ and hence $M_1e=(I-1(1'1)^{-1}1')e=e$.

This also means that $R^2$ is not necessarily larger than zero if $1\not\in\langle X\rangle$, as we would then have $M_{1}e\neq e$ in the 4th equality and hence $$e'M_{1}X\neq e'X=0,$$
and it would not necessarily be the case that $y'M_{1}y\geqslant e'e $ and thus $R^2\leqslant0$ becomes possible.

$R_u^2$ is by construction always between 0 and 1, but it is not a flawless alternative because it is not invariant against, for example, adding constant numbers $a$ to $y$, so that you would for example get different $R_u^2$ when explaining changing temperatures in Celsius or Fahrenheit.