# Computation of R-squared with lm() in R

Tags: r, r-squared, lm

Confusion on difference between the $R^2$ results from the `lm()` function in R and from the Equation

$1-rss/sst$        (1)

Ref: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/255/

```
z1 = c(0.603,0.643,0.603,0.643,0.643,0.603,0.601,0.641,0.601,0.603,0.601,0.641,0.643,0.641,0.641,0.601,0.622)
z2 = c(0.38,0.34,0.38,0.34,0.34,0.38,0.38,0.34,0.38,0.38,0.38,0.34,0.34,0.34,0.34,0.38,0.36)
z3= c(0.017,0.017,0.017,0.017,0.017,0.017,0.019,0.019,0.019,0.017,0.019,0.019,0.017,0.019,0.019,0.019,0.018)
z4= c(0.503505,0.536905,0.503505,0.536905,0.581915,0.545715,0.501835,0.535235,0.501835,0.545715,0.543905 ,0.535235,0.581915,0.580105,0.580105,0.543905,0.541140)
z5 = c(0.3420,0.3060,0.3724,0.3332,0.3060,0.3420,0.3420,0.3060,0.3724,0.3724,0.3420,0.3332,0.3332,0.3060,0.3332,0.3724,0.3384)
z = data.frame(z1,z2,z3,z4,z5)
y = c(35.040, 32.100, 37.800, 33.300, 31.320, 34.026, 34.140, 31.968, 36.990, 35.970, 33.870, 33.438, 33.144, 32.106, 33.660, 35.520, 33.438)

fit = lm(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 - 1, data = data.frame(y, z))

e = fit$residuals
rss = sum(e^2)
sst = sum((y-mean(y))^2)
1-rss/sst
```

> 0.9305206

```
summary(fit)$r.squared
```

> 0.9998195

I also checked `anova(fit)`. I think the $R^2$ results from `summary(fit)$r.squared` is correct. But why is the computation from Equation (1) wrong?

Comment: Take that -1 from model, try again. `fit = lm(y ~ z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5, data = data.frame(y, z))`

Comment: @user158565 Thanks for the quick reply. I tried to take the -1 off the formula, now the two methods are consistent. Does that mean the Equation (1) holds only when the intercept is considered in the linear regression model?

Comment: See also here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo

Comment: @Stefan Thanks so much, this link is useful and solves my problem.

Comment: Yes it is a very good answer indeed!