# Getting Different R-squared for Same Model Equation

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I have built two linear model in R using 'lm' function with some tricks as follows:

**Model-1: With default option**

```
l1 <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
```

**Model-2: Supplying the constant intercept (=1) variable manually and 'without Intercept' option**

```
Intercept = rep(1,50)
l2 <- lm(dist ~ 0 + Intercept + speed, data = cars)

summary(l1) # Multiple R-squared:  0.6511,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6438 
summary(l2) # Multiple R-squared:  0.9091,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9053
```

I have noticed, though both the model equation are identical but the R-squared and Adjusted R-squared has been increased significantly in the 2nd model. My questions are:

1. Why it is happening?
2. What are the alternative of R-squared, Adjusted R-squared which can catch this loophole?
3. Will this method give higher R-squared, Adjusted R-squared for any data?

Comment: If you replace `lm` by `model.matrix` and inspect the results, you will get a useful clue.  If that's not enough, compare your results to `l3 <- lm(dist ~ Intercept + speed, data = cars)`.  These will show the issue concerns the special way in which `summary` treats an intercept.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. I think, it is due to R sq. calculation. As per the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/removal-of-statistically-significant-intercept-term-increases-r2-in-linear-mo/26205#26205) the calculation is not same for 'With intercept' and 'Without Intercept'