# Why does R-Squared change with a no-intercept model?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, r-squared

Suppose I have one binary predictor $x$ and I fit an OLS model:

$$y = \alpha + \beta I(x=1) + \epsilon$$

Alternatively I can fit the following model

$$y = \beta I(x=1) + \beta I(x=0) + \epsilon$$

Why does the second model give me a higher R-Squared?

R example:

```
results <- numeric(1000)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  X <- rnorm(1000)
  b <- X > 0
  
  y <- rep(0, 1000)
  y[b == TRUE] <- 1
  
  y <- y + rnorm(1000)
  
  rsq0 <- summary(lm(y ~ b))$r.squared
  rsq1 <- summary(lm(y ~ b - 1))$r.squared
  
  results[i] <- rsq1 - rsq0
}

mean(results > 0) # This equals 1
```

Comment: plot the best fit line over the data scatter and see what difference it makes. You change the model by removing a component of it, so you expect its fit to change.

Comment: You do know that the definition of R² [is different for models with and without intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26176/11849)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Roland writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486090/why-does-r-squared-change-with-a-no-intercept-model/486097?noredirect=1#comment898081_486090), it comes down to the definition of $R^2$ in models with vs. without an intercept. More specifically, the difference lies in the calculation of the mean sum of squares.

We can inspect the code for `summary()` by simply typing `summary.lm` (without `()`). Here are the relevant parts:

```
> summary.lm
function (object, correlation = FALSE, symbolic.cor = FALSE, 
    ...) 
{
    z <- object
    ...
    r <- z$residuals
    f <- z$fitted.values
    ...
        mss <- if (attr(z$terms, "intercept")) 
            sum((f - mean(f))^2)
        else sum(f^2)
        rss <- sum(r^2)
    ...
    ans <- z[c("call", "terms", if (!is.null(z$weights)) "weights")]
    ...
        ans$r.squared <- mss/(mss + rss)

    ans
}
```

The crucial point is the distinction on `attr(z$terms, "intercept"))`, which is evaluated to `1` (converted to `TRUE`) in your first model, but `0` (or `FALSE`) in the second. In the first case, `mss` is calculated as the sum of the squared differences between fits and the overall mean, and in the second case, it is just the sum of the squared fitted values. We thus get different values for `mss`. The rest of the calculation is identical.

We can calculate an example and reconstruct the different $R^2$s by hand:

```
> nn <- 10
> set.seed(1)
> 
> X <- rnorm(nn)
> b <- X > 0
> y <- rep(0, nn)
> y[b == TRUE] <- 1
> y <- y + rnorm(nn)
>   
> model0 <- lm(y ~ b)
> model1 <- lm(y ~ b - 1)
> 
> mss0 <- sum((model0$fitted.values-mean(model0$fitted.values))^2)
> mss1 <- sum(model0$fitted.values^2)
> rss0 <- sum(model0$residuals^2)
> rss1 <- sum(model1$residuals^2)
> mss0/(mss0 + rss0)
[1] 0.1350045
> (rsq0 <- summary(model0)$r.squared)
[1] 0.1350045
> mss1/(mss1 + rss1)
[1] 0.4628321
> (rsq1 <- summary(model1)$r.squared)
[1] 0.4628321
```

Comment: That was a great answer by Stephan but, to be more succinct, it's really not correct to calculate $R^2$ in a no-intercept model because the sum of squares decomposition no longer holds.