# linear regression comparing two models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals

I am doing linear regression and predicting `y` using `constant,x1,x2,x,3,x4,....x10` (11 x variables) and I am getting `R^2 of 88.7% and R^2 adjusted of 85.1%`
I noticed that all x variables including the intercept have very high P values, indicating that they are not significant. Therefore I decide to build a model like below

predict `y` using `sum(x5...x10)`(summing 6 variables to get only 1 variable) and now I am getting `R^2 of 97.5% and R^2 adjusted of 97.5%`. I am not fitting an intercept in this case because value of `R^2 and  R^2 adjusted` is going down if I use the intercept and also P value of intercept is high indicating that it is not significant

In such case if I average absolute residuals for each model then the second model should have lower average right?

Comment: *squared* residuals, but yes probably the absolute ones too

Comment: oh wait, are you not including an intercept in the second model?

Comment: I am not including an intercept in the second model

Comment: That will mess with the $R^2$ values. Can you help us understand why you're not including an intercept? This should almost always be done.

Comment: what if after adding intercept the p value of value of intercept is very high, indicating that it is not significant?  I also updated the question

Comment: If you omit a parameter that was insignificant when you build a new model, you are doing some kind of stepwise regression and thus distorting later inferences (including estimates of performance like $R^2_{adj}$) unless great care is taken. // [R uses a different equation for $R^2$ when the intercept is omitted than when the intercept is included.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26205/247274) I am. It sure which software package you’re using, but even if it is not R, it might also exhibit this behavior.

Comment: If you include an intercept in both models--and you should--then it is mathematically guaranteed that the $R^2$ cannot increase when going from the complicated to the simpler model.  The *adjusted* $R^2$ could increase.  That would be an indication that the simplification *might* be worthwhile, but there are better ways to assess that.

Comment: @user2543622 Oh yeah you should keep the intercept in no matter what its p-value is :)

Comment: so if i keep the intercept then if the second model gets better R square then average absolute residuals for the second model should be lower, right?

Comment: @user2543622 Not necessarily: Model 1 could beat Model 2 on $R^2$ yet lose to Model 2 on another metric like mean absolute deviation.