# Random Forest: it's better to have lower error or a higher var explained?

Tags: r, random-forest, error

I'm specifically referring to Random Forest regression.

The first statistics that are usually printed after running a random forest regression  (in R - `randomForest` package - `randomForest:::print.randomForest`) are: 
`Mean of squared residuals` and `% Var explained` obtained.

Tuning the model, if you made a *"good"* change, usually you get a lower `Mean of squared residuals` and a higher `% Var explained`: is this always the case? (I'm aware of the fact that `randomForest` reports the *variation* and not the *variance* explained as specified here -> [Manually calculated $R^2$ doesn't match up with randomForest() $R^2$ for testing new data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/manually-calculated-r2-doesnt-match-up-with-randomforest-r2-for-testing])).

In case it is not, should I prefer a lower `Mean of squared residuals` or a higher `% Var explained`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the observed outputs are $Y = \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ with mean $\bar{y}$, and the predicted outputs are $\{\hat{y}_1, \dots, \hat{y}_n\}$. The mean squared error (MSE) is the mean of the squared residuals:

$$MSE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$$

The fraction of variance explained is defined as:

$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y}_i)^2}$$

Notice that the fraction above is equal to the mean squared error divided by the variance of $Y$:

$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{MSE}{Var(Y)}$$

Within the context of a *particular* set of $Y$ values, the variance of $Y$ is a constant, so $MSE$ and $R^2$ have a fixed relationship. A decrease in MSE implies an increase in $R^2$ and vice versa. Similarly, minimizing $MSE$ and maximizing $R^2$ are equivalent.